# Finite difference method for elliptic method MATLAB

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, approximation

Here is the question:

If R is the region of the plane (0,1) x (0,2), Let L be the 2-d Laplace operator and consider the Poisson equation Lu = 4 on R. One solution is the function v(x,y) = (x-y)^2. Let g be the restriction of v to the boundary of R. To obtain it, we set h = k = 1/2, and m=3, n =5.

Here is my code: but it doesn't work. Could someone help?

```
function w=poisson(xl,xr,yb,yt,M,N)
f=@(x,y) 0; % define input function data
g1=@(x) (x^2-2*x+1); % define boundary values
g2=@(x) (x^2-4*x+4); % Example 8.8 is shown
g3=@(y) y^2;
g4=@(y) y^2;
m=M+1;n=N+1; mn=m*n;
h=(xr-xl)/M;h2=h^2;k=(yt-yb)/N;k2=k^2;
x=xl+(0:M)*h; % set mesh values
y=yb+(0:N)*k;
A=zeros(mn,mn);b=zeros(mn,1);
for i=2:m-1 % interior points
  for j=2:n-1
    A(i+(j-1)*m,i-1+(j-1)*m)=1/h2;A(i+(j-1)*m,i+1+(j-1)*m)=1/h2;
    A(i+(j-1)*m,i+(j-1)*m)=-2/h2-2/k2;
    A(i+(j-1)*m,i+(j-2)*m)=1/k2;A(i+(j-1)*m,i+j*m)=1/k2;
    b(i+(j-1)*m)=f(x(i),y(j));
  end
end
for i=1:m % bottom and top boundary points
  j=1;A(i+(j-1)*m,i+(j-1)*m)=1;b(i+(j-1)*m)=g1(x(i));
  j=n;A(i+(j-1)*m,i+(j-1)*m)=1;b(i+(j-1)*m)=g2(x(i));
end
for j=2:n-1 % left and right boundary points
  i=1;A(i+(j-1)*m,i+(j-1)*m)=1;b(i+(j-1)*m)=g3(y(j));
  i=m;A(i+(j-1)*m,i+(j-1)*m)=1;b(i+(j-1)*m)=g4(y(j));
end
v=A\b; % solve for solution in v labeling
w=reshape(v(1:mn),m,n);  %translate from v to w
mesh(x,y,w')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix construction seems fine -- I didn't look into the the details. But I spotted a few apparent mistakes.

The source function $f(x,y)$ is wrong, it should equals 4 instead of 0;

The boundary functions (those g's) are wrong, they should be something like:

```
g1=@(y) (y^2-2*y+1); % right
g2=@(x) (x^2-4*x+4); % top
g3=@(x) x^2; % bottom
g4=@(y) y^2; % left
```

Then the two boundary loops should be changed accordingly

```
for i=1:m % bottom and top boundary points
  j=1;A(i+(j-1)*m,i+(j-1)*m)=1;b(i+(j-1)*m)=g3(x(i));
  j=n;A(i+(j-1)*m,i+(j-1)*m)=1;b(i+(j-1)*m)=g2(x(i));
end
for j=2:n-1 % left and right boundary points
  i=1;A(i+(j-1)*m,i+(j-1)*m)=1;b(i+(j-1)*m)=g4(y(j));
  i=m;A(i+(j-1)*m,i+(j-1)*m)=1;b(i+(j-1)*m)=g1(y(j));
end
```

Those were the only changes I made, after that, MATLAB draws the following picture with command

```
solPoisson(0,1,0,2,8,8)
```

[image: poisson]

Comment: Thank you very much! but I have a few questions: How to decide left, right, bottom and top functions correspondingly? And why are the m and n that you input are 8 and 8? Thanks!

Comment: Referring to the original code you posted, g1(x) is just $(x-1)^2$, which is setting $y=1$ in the $v(x,y) = (x-y)^2$ function. In the same way, at the top wall you have $x=x, y= 2$, so $v(x,2) = (x-2)^2$ which is just the g2 function. Others are the same. I choose $m$ and $n$ randomly, any value should fine.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much!

Comment: @J.doe You are very welcome.